# Can I create Azure MobileServiceClient instance with Azure Function App url instead of creating an Azure Mobile App?

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-functions, mobileserviceclient

My purpose is to build my mobile app backend serverless. 
Now, when I try to create MobileServiceClient instance, it asks for an Azure Mobile App URI, can this URI be an Function App URI or it has to be only Mobile App?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to handle the mobile apps server logic with functions, though you'll be rolling all of [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-node/blob/master/src/express/index.js) on your own.

One possibility: deploy a mobile app which uses the Azure Mobile Apps sdk at the root of your function app (they're both built on top of Web Apps). Then, use proxies / functions to handle any custom api calls from the mobile client so that you can convert over at your own pace.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. But i want to do it without deploying an mobile app. I want to have my functions to work just like rest api calls secured by custom authorization using Azure AD B2C tenant authentication. I thought I should have the flexibility without deploying an mobile app service plan which will cost extra money. Instead, i wanted to have some functions which can be reused later as well.

Comment: You should be able to do it with all functions - it's just rolling everything yourself that the mobile app backend does, which is significant. See the github link I posted - you basically need to recreate the express app in the mobile apps sdk.

Comment: Okay. That's actually good to know. Yes, you are right, I'm with you on that one. Thanks! I am yet to try using function app url though, I will keep you posted how it goes.